# unexpected behaviour with responsive css grid

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I've tried and ended up with
[i have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqX1W.png)

but I'm aiming for something more like the design shown in this image
[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc0CN.png)

his means I want each item to only take up the space it needs, rather than expanding to match the size of the largest item in the row. Is there a way to achieve this?

my code :

```
    'use client';

import React from 'react';

import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { SxProps, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

import Container from 'shared/layout/Container';

type Props = {
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
  cards: {
    title: string;
    items: string[];
  }[];
};

const NoiceList: React.FC<Props> = ({ cards, sx }) => (
  <Container sx={{
    mt: 50,
  }}
  >
    <Box sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      gap: 6,
    }}
    >
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <Box sx={{
          border: '1px solid #9F9F9F',
          p: 6,
        }}
        >
          <Box key={card.title}>
            <Typography variant="body2" sx={{ mb: 3 }}>{card.title}</Typography>
            <Box
              component="ul"
              sx={{
                display: 'grid',
                gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(190px, 1fr) )',
              }}
            >
              {card.items.map((item) => (
                <Box
                  component="li"
                  sx={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'baseline',
                    gap: 2,
                    py: 1,
                    px: 2,
                  }}
                  key={item}
                >
                  <Box sx={{ height: 7 }}>
                    <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'secondary.400', width: 4, height: 4, borderRadius: '100%' }} />
                  </Box>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="secondary.500" sx={{ lineHeight: 'normal' }}>{item}</Typography>
                </Box>
              ))}
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </Box>
  </Container>
);

export default NoiceList;
```

Comment: A grid is a grid – everything is arranged in **rows and columns**. To achieve what you want, you can either use a [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, or you can use [**columns**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp). ([columns example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053186/2518285))